# ORDER BY no funciona MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

tengo complicacion con la siguiente sentencia para seleccionar todos los siguientes campos pero ordenar por "FECHA"

```
SELECT CREDITO, DATE_FORMAT(FECHA_PROM, '%W %d de %M %Y') AS FECHA_PROM, CR, COMENTARIO, 
MONTO_PP, AGENTE, DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%W %d de %M del %Y, %h:%m %p') AS FECHA, TELEFONO 
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM comentarios
    WHERE CREDITO = '123456789' 
) AS COMENTARIOS ORDER BY FECHA DESC;
```

No esta aplicando el "ORDER BY" ni en DESC ni en ASC, cabe mencionar que setee MySQL para que me regrese la fecha en formato "es_MX" con

```
mysqli_query($mysql_conexion, "SET lc_time_names = 'es_MX'");
```

Si genero la sentencia de manera normal si aplica el "ORDER BY" ¿Qué tengo mal?

Comment: Hola, cuando traes los datos usas algo como data tables o alguna libreria para mostrarlos?

Comment: Sí, exactamente... ¡Si uso DATATABLES! ¿Qué ocurre?
Pero también genero la consulta desde Workbench y ni así funcionar el ORDER BY

Comment: A mi me paso trabajando con data tables, debes dar el valor false el order de datatables asi: $('#example').dataTable( {
  "ordering": false
} ); al declarar ese valor false, la tabla se ordena por lo que declares en la consulta de mysql

Comment: Ya me auto-respondi mi propia pregunta, revisa la respuesta

Comment: Hola, me puedes decir si la respuesta dada te sirvio, gracias

Answer (score 3):

No uses el alias que le pones a la columna obtenida:

```
SELECT CREDITO, DATE_FORMAT(FECHA_PROM, '%W %d de %M %Y') AS FECHA_PROM, CR, COMENTARIO, 
MONTO_PP, AGENTE, DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%W %d de %M del %Y, %h:%m %p') AS FECHA, TELEFONO 
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM comentarios
    WHERE CREDITO = '123456789' 
) AS COMENTARIOS ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%W %d de %M del %Y, %h:%m %p') DESC;
```

Haces tu consulta pero en el **order by** pon lo mismo que pones en el **select**, es decir:

```
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%W %d de %M del %Y, %h:%m %p') DESC
```

De esta forma debes ordenar bien, ya que el alias no es válido para usarse como campo para ordenar.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CREDITO, DATE_FORMAT(FECHA_PROM, '%W %d de %M %Y') AS FECHA_PROM, CR, 
COMENTARIO, MONTO_PP, AGENTE, DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%W %d de %M del %Y, %h:%m %p') 
AS FECHA_FORMATEADA, TELEFONO 
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM comentarios
    WHERE CREDITO = '123456789' 
) AS COMENTARIOS ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%W %d de %M del %Y, %h:%m %p') 
DESC;
```

Mi problema radicaba en que si ordenaba pero en base al texto que daba el AS FECHA al formatear, pasa de ser fecha a texto plan y lo ordenaba de manera alfabética y no por fecha, lo que hice es que cambien el "AS de FECHA" a "AS FECHA_FORMATEADA" ya de esa manera tomaba valor fecha y no texto y ordena de manera correcta y con el formato que solicite "es_MX", bueno a mi me funciono de esa manera, no se si lleguese a pasar por las DATATABLES

Comment: No es asi, a ti te funciono porque en el order by pusiste ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%W %d de %M del %Y, %h:%m %p'), el campo puede quedarse como fecha si quieres, o llamarlo pepe da lo mismo, lo unico que debias hacer es quitar el alias del order by